# Square root of a complex symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices

Is it possible to express a complex symmetric matrix $A$ as square of a matrix $B$ (i.e. $A = B^2$)? If $A$ were Hermitian, we could use Spectral Theorem to get $A = UDU^{-1}$ where $D$ has diagonal entries being eigenvalues of $A$. However, here $A$ being a complex symmetric seems to not give us any useful tools. The Takagi decomposition does not give us nice way to find a matrix for $A^{1/2}$ as well. Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}i & 1 \\ 1 & -i \end{pmatrix}.$$

Its Jordan canonical form is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$

which has no square root. So it cannot have a square root since they are similar.

Comment: If you have not yet encountered the Jordan form, you just need to know that the matrices are similar. The explicit similarity transform is given [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Bi,1%7D,%7B1,-i%7D%7D) under the heading 'Jordan decomposition'.